# MySQL ERROR 1265: Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, truncated

I can't figure out why I'm getting this message. I'm using MySQL Workbench and am editing the values in an ENUM field that connects to a dropdown choice in my app.

Everything seems to be fine. I've searched on this error and all I find refers to datatype mismatches but, in this instance, that's not possible with ENUM when feeding it an array of string values.

Here's the SQL

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `mydbase`.`average_monthly_expenses` 
CHANGE COLUMN `expense_category` `expense_category` ENUM('Home', 'Healthcare', 'Child care', 'Groceries and supplies', 'Eating out', 'Utilities', 'Telecomms', 'Laundry and cleaning', 'Clothes', 'Education', 'Entertainment gifts vacation', 'Auto and transportation', 'Insurance', 'Savings and investments', 'Charitable contributions', 'Itemized monthly payments') NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1265: Data truncated for column 'expense_category' at row 1
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `mydbase`.`average_monthly_expenses` 
CHANGE COLUMN `expense_category` `expense_category` ENUM('Home', 'Healthcare', 'Child care', 'Groceries and supplies', 'Eating out', 'Utilities', 'Telecomms', 'Laundry and cleaning', 'Clothes', 'Education', 'Entertainment gifts vacation', 'Auto and transportation', 'Insurance', 'Savings and investments', 'Charitable contributions', 'Itemized monthly payments') NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Any suggestions are very welcome

Answer (score 1):

@Akina

So I figured out why I was blocked from editing the values. It would not let me make any edits that changed either value "Housing" or "Other". I did as you suggested, adding my new values to the existing ones, no problem, that worked fine. I couldn't however delete "Housing" or "Other", but the other prior values deleted fine. For the moment, I kept both, using "Housing" instead of "Home" and leaving "Other" at the end.

But I wanted to know however why those two values were protected, and then it dawned on me, there were existing records using those values. I manually changed all instances using "Other" to "Telecomms" and then I could remove "Other" from the ENUM values. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is correct.

[modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eadef49cc0ccaef726ba2268cbb1a531)

Execute

```
SELECT DISTINCT expense_category, HEX(expense_category) 
FROM mydbase.average_monthly_expenses
```

and check the output for the values which are not listed in the column definition.

There may be typos, leading/trailing spaces or another non-printed symbols, double spaces in the middle of the value, or there may be some collation problems.

---

**UPDATE**

> My current field definition I'm trying to change to the above is ENUM('Home', 'Living', 'Telecommunications', 'Transportation', 'Other'). When I run your suggested SQL I just get **Housing** and **Other** listed.

These values are absent in new column definition - so server cannot convert them and truncates the values.

Recommendations: alter column definition, add new values to ENUM values list but do not remove old ones; update table and replace old values with new ones; alter column definition and remove old values from the list.

Comment: That's weird. My current field definition I'm trying to change to the above is `ENUM('Home', 'Living', 'Telecommunications', 'Transportation', 'Other')`. When I run your suggested SQL I just get `Housing` and `Other` listed. Removing `DISTINCT` gives same two values but repeated twice (i.e., 4 values). I wonder if there's a different single quote mark I should be using to delimit the values in the statement?

Comment: @Hondaman900 Please add this info into your query text.

Comment: @Hondaman900 Answer updated according your information.